# How to map @OneToMany to a java.util.Map with custom keys?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
class A{

  private List<B> bs;

  ...
}

class B{

  private Long id;
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

---

And I'd like to have this:

```
class A{

  // the map should have B.name as key
  private Map<String,B> bs;

  ...
}

class B{
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private A a;
  ...
}
```

---

I don't know if it is clear what I'd like to do, but it is as simple as mapping a one to many relationship to a Map with the name of B as the key of the map.

Thanks in advance,
Neuquino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the hibernate annotation MapKey

```
@MapKey(name = "name")
@OneToMany()
private Map<String,B> bs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Collections has a class with this facility.  Try it.